# wso2 API Mananger 2.0.0 + API Manager Analytics 2.0.0 billing integration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

There are several summary tables[API Manager summarized tables (DAS internal storage)](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Introducing+the+WSO2+API+Manager+Statistics+Model#IntroducingtheWSO2APIManagerStatisticsModel-APIManagerstatistics),

1. Which one will be used for **billing**? API_REQUEST_SUMMARY? API_THROTTLED_OUT_SUMMARY? or no one and need to create own cApp?
2. Is API_REQUEST_SUMMARY include all success request & fault & throttle out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use API_REQUEST_SUMMARY as it contains all successful API invocations. API_THROTTLED_OUT_SUMMARY table having both throttled requests and successful requests. Since API_REQUEST_SUMMARY is having only successful requests you may use it for billing purpose.

[image]
Thanks,

sanjeewa.

Comment: Except summary request, some customers also request detail transaction details as part of billing, how can i get them? custom handler? or write one spark SQL to transform them to external store?